# Convert the output of ls in a python list

Tags: python, linux

I get the listing of a directory using bash command `ls`(can't use python on remote)

How can I convert the return of `ls` from remote in a python list/set containing filenames?

Comment: you have to provide the sample of the input and sample of the output if you're looking for someone seriously considering answering you.

Comment: How are you running `ls` in a python environment? Are you running it in a shell, redirecting it to a file? Are you using `subprocess.run`? Are you using `!ls` in IPython? In the first two you can just use the `str.splitlines` method. In the latter you already get a list. If your ultimate goal is to get the contents of a directory in python, I would instead recommend `glob.glob` or `pathlib.Pathlib.glob`.

Comment: @Andrew, the ls is execute on remote machine, and I get the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can just use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), like this:

```py
import os
files = os.listdir()
```

**EDIT:** if you have any control over the `ls` cmd, you can add the `-1` flag, to get one filename per line, then use `.splitlines()` to turn it into a list.

regular `split` on the regular `ls` would fail on filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: I can't use python on the machine, where I execute `ls,` this is way I don't use python os to get the files.

Comment: @user3541631 OK, gotcha, so you just get the output as a string?

Comment: yes the output is from console

Comment: @user3541631 `split` would have problem dealing with, any chance you can run `ls -1` instead of just `ls`? that way you can get one file per line